# What multiple comparisons correction should i use?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multiple-comparisons, familywise-error

I have a couple of situations in which I am unsure as to which statistical FWER correction to use.

1) This will lead to a paper.

I have 1 group of people that was tested twice with certain questions (Pre-Post). Multiple Mann Whitney U tests were run. I am attempting to correct for multiple comparisons, while using the most powerful and appropriate method.

I am comparing the methods Holm, Hommel, and maybe even Rom, but I am having issues feeling confident that I understand and can check the assumptions properly.

I believe that I understand the assumption of positive dependence, i.e. My variables are positively correlated, and Independent.

I am not sure that I understand stochastic ordering, or any other assumptions I may have missed.

To give you a visual

```
Group A Before      Group A After
     Q1                 Q1
     Q2                 Q2
     Q3                 Q4
```

Same group of people, just pre and post test.

What is the most powerful, and appropriate FWER that can be used in this situation. (Comparing the same people with a pre and post test)?

2) This situation is basically the same as situation 1), but is for a poster rather than a paper. (Not a statistics poster, but one in the medical field rather)

How common / appropriate is it to use multiple comparisons corrections for posters?